# mysql - joins with sub queries with sub query where conditions using main query fields

Tags: mysql

i have a complaint table

```
|------------------------|
|    cid    |    desc    |
|------------------------|
|     1     |  faulty    |
|     2     |  broken    |
|     3     |  spoiled   |
|------------------------|
```

and an assignment table

```
|------------------------------------|
|     aid   |    cid    |    empid   |
|------------------------------------|
|     1     |     1     |     1      |
|     2     |     1     |     5      |
|     3     |     2     |     2      |
|     4     |     2     |            |
|     5     |     3     |     2      |
|     6     |     3     |     7      |
|------------------------------------|
```

each complaint can be assigned to atmost two employees
i need to display a list in the below format

```
|---------------------------------------------------|
|    cid    |    desc    |   emp1id   |    emp2id   |
|------------------------|--------------------------|
|     1     |  faulty    |     1      |      5      |
|     2     |  broken    |     2      |             |
|     3     |  spoiled   |     2      |      7      |
|------------------------|--------------------------|
```

i wrote the query like this

```
select c.cid, c.desc, a1.empid as emp1id, a2.empid as emp2id
from complaint c 
left join (
    select aid, cid, empid
    from assignment aa 
    where aa.cid = c.cid 
    limit 0,1 
) as a1 on a1.cid = c.cid
left join (
    select aid, cid, empid
    from assignment ab
    where ab.cid = c.cid
    limit 1,1
) as a2 on a2.cid = c.cid
```

but it is not working, i am getting error for c.cid in sub queries. how to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: Which one is emp1?

Comment: And it looks as though a complaint can be assigned to nobody. Is that correct?

Comment: "Which one is emp1?" @Strawberry the one offcource which is "first" inserted?? 
laxmi nagireddi SQL is by definition **orderless** you need some kind off column which you can use to identify the order and you can use `ORDER BY` on.. Like a id column with auto_increment option which your data in the assignment table clearly does not have

Comment: @RaymondNijland Why 'of course'. Do you have some insider knowledge?

Comment: Why 'of course'. Do you have some insider knowledge? @Strawberry No i don't it was just a educated guess don't we see this kind off questions alot on stackoverflow?? Where the topicstarters assume SQL retains insert order when selecting without using `ORDER BY` on a column that identifies the order?

Comment: We do, and we let the OP clarify their question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work? (I don't have mySql installed)

```
select  c.cid, 
        c.desc, 
        (
            select aid, cid, empid
            from assignment aa 
            where aa.cid = c.cid 
            limit 0,1 
        ) as emp1id, 
        (
            select aid, cid, empid
            from assignment ab
            where ab.cid = c.cid
            limit 1,1
        ) as emp2id
from complaint c
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland how about the above

Comment: @Janine Rawnsley,i posted a simplified version of my actual query, will test it and let you know.

Comment: @laxminagireddi did you read our comments? About insert order in SQL?